# Unable to get list of USB ports on Mac

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I am using below code to list the available ports using node-serialport npm:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
SerialPort.list(function(err, ports){console.dir(ports); console.dir(err)});
```

It lists only the Bluetooth port, but, not the USB ports

Below is the output that I am getting:

```
[ { comName: '/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port',
    manufacturer: undefined,
    serialNumber: undefined,
    pnpId: undefined,
    locationId: undefined,
    vendorId: undefined,
    productId: undefined } ]
null
```

I have OSX Captain installed and there are two USB ports which aren't being listed here.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the some question, you can refer to my practice.

I install the drive of usb, and will get it message.

```
{ comName: '/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART',
  manufacturer: 'Silicon Labs',
  serialNumber: '0001',
  pnpId: undefined,
  locationId: '0x14200000',
  vendorId: '0x10c4',
  productId: '0xea60' }
```